# Discord.js : TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hey I've tried many thing but this code doesn't works, sorry for not including so much details but I really don't know what's wrong with this code

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client()
const db = require('quick.db');
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(client.user.tag);
});
console.log(client.channels.get(`688901992826929210`))
```

Console:

```
TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:9:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I'm using glitch.com free hosting, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't appear to have logged into your client using `client.login('INSERT TOKEN HERE')` so client.channels is likely undefined and therefore .get() is not a function.

Also if you happen to be using the new Discord.js v12 this will now be `client.channels.cache.get()` but you still have to log in using your bot token.

Comment: Client is logged I just not included that but I'll try with client.channels.cache.get, ty!

Comment: I solved problem by downgrading discordjs version but that actually works so im marking as accepted

Comment: Adding `.cache` before `.get()` as this user stated worked for me, thank you kindly - I wondered why I could see the data but no function existed...