# Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined - any assistance appreciated

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So basically, I'm getting this error when trying to launch my bot.  It is built using Discord.js

```
/home/container/events/serverStats.js:5
const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('XX');
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/events/serverStats.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:83:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
```

The code file itself looks like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../settings/config.js');
const client = require('../index.js');
const Guild_ID = require('../settings/configuration').BOT_SETTINGS;
const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('858369874110971914');
const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('858370257797513236');
const codeMonkeys = client.channels.fetch('858370529902985227');

client.guilds.fetch('XX')
  .then(guild => console.log(guild.name))
  .catch(console.error);
```

This is what my index file looks like:

```
require('./structures/Guild')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Collection, Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Manager } = require('@lavacord/discord.js')
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { BOT_TOKEN, EMBED_COLOR, MUTE_ROLE, YT_API_KEY, COMMAND_PREFIX } = require("./settings/configuration").BOT_SETTINGS;
const db = require('quick.db')
const path = require("path");
const logSymbols = require('log-symbols');
const Enmap = require('enmap');
const Tickets = new Enmap({ name: 'tickets' });
const i18n = require('i18n');
client.tickets = Tickets;
if (!COMMAND_PREFIX) throw new Error('Please provide a prefix in the configuration')
if (!BOT_TOKEN) throw new Error('Please provide a valid bot token to start the bot\nObtain one from here https://discord.com/developers/applications')
if (!YT_API_KEY) throw new Error('Please provide a Youtube API key in the configuration.\nGet one here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started')
if (!EMBED_COLOR) throw new Error('Please provide an embed hex color in the configuration. E.g. RED or #fl92jd')

console.log(logSymbols.success, 'Finished successfully!');

client.StickyMessages = new db.table(`sticky`)
const StickyMessages = new db.table(`sticky`)

client.db = require('quick.db')
client.embed = class Embed extends MessageEmbed { color = EMBED_COLOR }


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Watching you!`, {
        type: "WATCHING"
    });

});
i18n.configure({
  locales: ["en", "ko", "fr", "pt_br", "zh_cn", "zh_tw"],
  directory: path.join(__dirname, "locales"),
  defaultLocale: "en",
  objectNotation: true,
  register: global,
  logErrorFn: function (msg) {
    console.log("error", msg);
  },

  missingKeyFn: function (locale, value) {
    return value;
  },

  mustacheConfig: {
    tags: ["{{", "}}"],
    disable: false
  }
});

client.snipes = new Collection()
client.commands = new Collection();
client.color = EMBED_COLOR;
client.muteRole = MUTE_ROLE;
client.afk = new Collection()
client.spam = new Collection()
    //client.handle = require("./functions/handle");
    //client.play = require("./functions/play");
client.queue = new Collection()
client.categories = new Collection()

client.db = {
    ...require('quick.db'),
    ensure: (key, def) => {
        if (db.get(key)) return db.get(key)
        db.set(key, def)
        return db.get(key, def)
    }
}
client.manager = new Manager(client, [{ id: 'main', host: 'localhost', port: 2333, password: 'brandon2511' }])
client.manager.on('ready', node => console.log(`Node ${node.id} is ready!`))
    .on('disconnect', (ws, node) => console.log(`Node ${node.id} disconnected.`))
    .on('reconnecting', node => console.log(`Node ${node.id} tries to reconnect.`))
    .on('error', (error, node) => console.log(`Node ${node.id} got an error: ${error.message}`))

const eventFiles = readdirSync("./events").filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    if (event.name) {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(client, ...args));
        console.log(`[√] Event ${file} has been successfully loaded!`);
    }
}

const categories = ['fun', 'info', 'moderation', 'system', 'tickets', 'basic', 'music'];
categories.forEach(async category => {
    const commandFiles = readdirSync(`./commands/${category}`).filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"));
    if (category !== 'owner') client.categories.set(category, commandFiles.map(s => s.split('.')[0]))
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        try {
            const command = require(`./commands/${category}/${file}`);
            if (command.config) {
                client.commands.set(file.split('.')[0], { name: file.split('.')[0], ...command });
                console.log(`[√] Command ${file.split('.')[0]} has been successfully loaded!`);
            } else throw new Error('Command missing config')
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`[❌] Command ${file} failed to load: ${e.message}`)
        }
    }
});

client.login(BOT_TOKEN).catch(() =>
    console.log(
        `[❌] Error while trying bot to log in.
  [⚠️ POSSIBLE FIX] You provided an invalid token of the bot`
    )
);
```

And this is the first part of my config file:

```
module.exports = {
    BOT_SETTINGS: {
        BOT_TOKEN: 'XX',
        YT_API_KEY: 'XX',
        COMMAND_PREFIX: '?',
        EMBED_COLOR: 'BLUE',
        MUTE_ROLE: '841079005892968458',
        BANNED_WORDS: ['retard', 'nigger'],
        BYPASS_ROLES: ['802711739006582846'],
        BANNED_LINKS: ['www.', '.com', '.net', '.gov', '.co', '.uk', '.gg', '.live'],
        BYPASS_LINKS_ROLES: ["802711739006582846"],
        Member_Count_Channel: '809569469030596648',
        Guild_ID: '802700035544317972',
        Kick_On_Warnings: true,
        Warnings_Until_Kick: '5',
        Time_Muted: '1m',
        LOCALE: 'en',
        Roles_On_Join: ['803388467588628490']
    },
```

Any ideas, please?  I have tried all the obvious amendments and this has been keeping me up for 72 hours!  I am truly stuck as to what the issue(s) is/are and their fixes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js : TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60699620/discord-js-typeerror-client-channels-get-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Sadly not; I have tried adding .cache and now it's throwing the same error at .cache instead, and still referring me to the index?